# Ghostscript - import multiple files at once

Tags: pdf, import, ghostscript, placeholder

I am new to ghostscript and I cannot figure out the syntax to import multiple files at once to merge them to a single file.

I tried several placeholders (e.g. $_*#%) to import ~100 pdf files but unfortunately the placeholders are not working.

Below you can see my source code:

```
gswin.exe -dQUIET -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=C:\Users\xxx\pdf\output.pdf C:\Users\xxx\test1".pdf C:\Users\xxx\test2".pdf
```

I need something like

```
gswin.exe -dQUIET -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=C:\Users\xxx\pdf\output.pdf C:\Users\xxx\test*.pdf
```

to import all files named like test1.pdf, test2.pdf, test3.pdf,...

**Thank you.**

Comment: You cannot use wildcards on the Ghostscript command line. You need to specify each file individually. Since this can become large, and exceed the shell limit on the size of the line, you can put all the arguments in a file then use the '@filename' syntax (see documentation https://ghostscript.com/doc/current/Use.htm#General_switches)

Answer (score -1):

On Windows (in contrast to Unix/Linux) the command prompt/shell does not generally perform wild card expansion automatically and it is up to individual command line applications whether they implement it. Many native command line applications do but GhostScript, for instance, does not.

If you use Windows PowerShell instead of Command Prompt (cmd.exe), it offers some ways of doing wildcard expansion on the command line. See for example the [`Resolve-Path`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/resolve-path?view=powershell-5.1) or [`Convert-Path`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/convert-path?view=powershell-5.1) cmdlets, both of which resolve wildcards.

For example, the following might work for you in PowerShell:

```
gswin.exe -dQUIET -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile="C:\Users\xxx\pdf\output.pdf" (Convert-Path "C:\Users\xxx\test*.pdf")
```